# Fully understand prefix increment (++) operation

Tags: c

I have the following code and I expect the output is:

```
foo(0) -- 2   /* 1*2 */
foo(2) -- 12  /* 3*4 */
foo(4) -- 30  /* 5*6 */
```

but I've got

```
foo(2) -- 4
foo(4) -- 16
foo(6) -- 36
```

instead. Can someone explain to me what happened?

```
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter;    /* counter for loop */

    counter = 0;

    while (counter < 5)
        printf("foo(%d) -- %d\n", counter, ((++counter)*(++counter)));

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Once you've used `++` -- prefix or postfix -- on a variable, you can't use it again on the same variable until after the next [sequence point](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/sequence_points.html).  If you do, the behavior of the code is undefined -- the compiler is allowed to do *anything it wants*.

There are no sequence points between the two `(++counter)` expressions in your code, so you've run afoul of this rule.  You have to write something like this, instead:

```
while (counter < 5) {
    printf("foo(%d) -- %d\n", counter, (counter+1) * (counter+2));
    counter += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`(++counter)*(++counter)` is actually *undefined behaviour* in C since a variable is modified twice without a sequence point (i.e. a `;`) in between. The result may vary across different compilers. Some may opt-in to format your hard disk instead, but luckily your compiler hasn't.

Apart from this, there's little to be understood about prefix-increment. `bar(++i)` is shorthand for

```
i += 1;
bar(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix increment means the increment is done before the remainder of the operations. To my knowledge the official requirement is that the evaluation of ++counter is not the original value.

It is likely being expanded as an increment before the statement like so:

```
 counter = counter + 1;
 counter = counter + 1;
 printf("foo(%d) -- %d\n", counter, ((counter)*(counter)));
```

Which would create the behavior you are seeing. My recommendation is to avoid stress testing these kinds of corner cases too much.

Answer (score 0):

you are expecting it to do

++c = 1
*
++c = 2

= 1*2 = 2

What is actually happening is

++c = 2
*
++c = 2

= 4

As other have pointed out - this is undefined behavior. the compiler is not required to reveal its inner working unless you force it to by breaking complex statements up into smaller pieces